# Why do we need NgRX even we can do everything with services?

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-services, angular-state-managmement

I've worked on some Angular 2+ projects and I'm still wondering why we do need NgRX.
I could implement everything with services and it seems that they are easier to understand.
I'm not sure if this is because I'm not familiar with NgRX, but anyway I couldn't find the certain use case for NgRX.
Can anyone give me some explanations regarding the following?

- difference between state implementation by NgRx and Services
- pros and cons of each implementation
- what do we need to consider when implementing the NgRX?
- any concerns with performance?

Comment: for example u have some like this: a = new SomeClass(...); u can modify it and when save to ngrx storage. after u try get a (refresh page) u will have same data in "a", and it will be class, not object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be a rather `ngrx`-pro post since I have been using it for nearly 3 years now. I have seen a lot of times where it went offboard and managing the `ngrx`-state became a pain but mostly it was due to disregard of application architecture and best pratices. When applied right it is a pleasure to write and review `ngrx` code because things have a strict structure.

IMHO: It can be used in any application, it really makes sense in bigger ones. All that `ngrx` can do for you can also be built using services but on the long run that will get harder and harder. By the time you realize you needed it, it will be too late.

Here is an article discussing it all.

https://blog.strongbrew.io/do-we-really-need-redux/

> difference between state implementation by NgRx and Services

While `ngrx` is pretty opinionted about how to read/update/write data, services leave much more up to the developer. I tend to prefer CRUD operations to be opitinionated for consistency.

- Angular Services usually expose `Observables` which hold data and functions to update data in said `Observables`. Often this means that we end up re-creating CRUD operations in each of these services.
- `ngrx` exposes data as `selectors` and update/delete functions as `actions`. On top of that there are `effects` to deal with async operations. There is a clear distinction between reading and writing as the logic happens in differnt places as opposed to Service classes which do all-in-one mostly.
- Angular services make it really easy to build private state management in some classes which is generally discouragd.

> pros and cons of each implementation

There are a few things which make `ngrx` valuable, e.g. its extensions but they need to be used and configured right. The main value for me is the consistency it gives.

- The devtools make it much easier to understand which values were updated when and how often. Debugging this with console logs is a pain:

  - https://ngrx.io/guide/store-devtools
- There is an `@ngrx/entity`-package which makes managing collections much easier because it provides methods such as `upsertOne` or `updateMany` which have clearly-defined types. It also provides easy access by generating selectors:

  - https://ngrx.io/guide/entity
- The `@ngrx/data` is an extension of `@ngrx/entity` package takes away writing a lot of services by providing API methods to update/delete... entities

  - https://ngrx.io/guide/data
- You can always extend `@ngrx/effects` using your own services.

> any concerns with performance?

Performance can be affected if `@ngrx` best practices are disregarded:

- https://blog.strongbrew.io/Redux-best-practices
- **Keep the state as flat as possible**
- `ngrx` selectors which were created with `createSelector` are memoized, which means that they will only ever trigger changes when the state changes. This is a performance-pro for `ngrx`, to re-implement this in a sea of services can be a lot of work

  - [https://medium.com/swlh/memoization-with-selectors-in-ngrx-c60e67a08161#:~:text=NgRx%20selectors%20help%20retrieve%20subset,of%20the%20features%20of%20Selectors](https://medium.com/swlh/memoization-with-selectors-in-ngrx-c60e67a08161#:%7E:text=NgRx%20selectors%20help%20retrieve%20subset,of%20the%20features%20of%20Selectors).

> what do we need to consider when implementing the NgRX?

Get your best practices right as soon as possible.